# Extracting certain parts of rows of a data_frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

suppose, our data-frame is as follows-

(1, Mr. John, 20000)
(2, Mr. Leo, 50000)
(3, Miss Anne, 30000)
(4, Mrs. Gerald, 35000)

I want to extract only(Mr., Miss, Mrs.) from the 'names'column and store it in a vector,
how can i do this?

Comment: Hi chinmaya kalo and welcome to SO ! When asking a question it is best practice to provide a reproducible example and format the code in your question. You can find all the ways to do so here : [how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) . (+1 to upvote your question to 0).

Comment: Hi Chinmaya, if you found any of the answers useful, please mark it so.

Answer (score 1):

Does this help?

```
> df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4), name = c('Mr. John', 'Mr. Leo', 'Miss Anne', 'Mrs. Gerald'), sal = c(20000, 50000, 30000, 35000), stringsAsFactors = 0)
> df
  id        name   sal
1  1    Mr. John 20000
2  2     Mr. Leo 50000
3  3   Miss Anne 30000
4  4 Mrs. Gerald 35000
> vec <- gsub('(^M.+)\\s([A-z].+)', '\\1', df$name)
> vec
[1] "Mr."  "Mr."  "Miss" "Mrs."
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach using `dplyr` (and the data frame created by Karthik):

```
vec <- as.vector(separate(df, name, sep = " ", into = "title", extra = "drop")[2])
```

Where `df` is your data frame, `name` is whatever name you have for your names column. You use `sep` to decide how to split the string up, `into` lets you choose the name of your new column (if you were keeping it as a column), `extra` lets you choose whether or not to display a warning (you are getting rid of surname so you would get a warning otherwise). The `[2]`, shows you just want to keep the second column, which is the one you newly created. `as.vector` converts it to a vector.

If you wanted to add separate the names column into two columns (i.e title and surname) and keep them inside your data frame, you could do:

```
df2 <- separate(df, name, sep = " ", into = c("title", "surname"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this, I don't know if sapply could be an option here as well, your data frame is also incorrectly defined, I suppose df is the df you have...

```
df=data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,4), name=c("Mr. John","Mr. Leo","Miss Anne", "Mrs. Gerald"), 
value=c(20000,50000,30000,35000))

splitted_name=strsplit(df$name," ")
a=character(0)
for (i in splitted_name)  a=append(a,i[1])
print(a)
```